# How do I get Google Notifier (Mac) to report the number of new messages in Priority Inbox?

Tags: snow-leopard, email, google

I'm using Google Notifier for Mac 1.10.6.879 and I want it to report the number of new messages in Priority Inbox. Previously, I had Notifier report the number of unread messages that had a certain label assigned to it (it was a quasi-Priority Inbox). I set up the notifier by going into terminal and typing:

```
defaults write com.google.GmailNotifier Label -string "LABEL"
```

When I substitute out LABEL for Priority Inbox, it doesn't provide an accurate unread count:

```
defaults write com.google.GmailNotifier Label -string "Priority Inbox"
```

Doesn't it make complete sense that Google Notifier and Priority Inbox should work together?!

Comment: This still shows old and read messages. How do you fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the label GMail uses for the Priority Inbox is "Important". Have you tried using that?